# File transfer with Azure Bastion using Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-bastion

Is there a way to perform file upload with Azure Bastion using Azure PowerShell commands.

The deployment of Bastion covered in the link provided below does not cover the file upload/download steps using Azure PowerShell commands.

[Deploy Bastion using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-create-host-powershell)

The below steps in Azure CLI is what I'm trying to achieve using Azure PowerShell commands. [CLI link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/vm-upload-download-native)

```
az network bastion tunnel --name "<BastionName>" --resource-group "<ResourceGroupName>" --target-resource-id "<VMResourceId>" --resource-port "<TargetVMPort>" --port "<LocalMachinePort>"

scp -P <LocalMachinePort>  <local machine file path>  <username>@127.0.0.1:<target VM file path>
```